# Which exclamatory sentence is correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

> 1. How painful traffic jam is sometimes!
> 2. How painful sometimes traffic jam is!

Can anyone please tell me which exclamatory sentence is correct?

Comment: Improve your question by explaining why you think there is a problem, and why you doubt the correctness of both expressions.

Comment: Both questions are incorrect. Hint: "traffic jam" is a countable noun

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Jam (made with fruit) is an uncountable noun, but a traffic jam is countable.

It would be natural to use the plural to speak of traffic jams in general.  The adverb "sometimes" can be placed before or after the verb.

> How painful traffic jams sometimes are!
>
> How painful traffic jams are sometimes!

Style: The use of "painful" is figurative and hyperbolic.  That's not wrong but it makes the sentence seem unusual.  If you have chosen this word carefully you can use it. If you have chosen this word because it fits the idiom of your native language, then consider replacing it.

The idiom "How + adjective!" seems to be in many ESL texts.  It's not actually that common.

Suggestion:  You can indicate the fact that traffic jams have the potential to be painful better by using a modal verb instead of (or in addition to) an adverb.  You can emphasise the hyperbole by italics to show how this would be stressed if spoken.

> How *painful* traffic jams can be!